# Find confidence of prediction in SVM

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning, svm

I am doing English digit classification using SVM classifier in opencv. 
I am able to predict the classes using `predict()` function. 
But I want get confidence of prediction between 0-1. Can somebody provide a method to do it using opencv

```
 //svm parameters used
 m_params.svm_type    = CvSVM::C_SVC;
 m_params.kernel_type = CvSVM::RBF;
 m_params.term_crit   = cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 500, 1e-8);

 //for training
 svmob.train_auto(m_features, m_labels, cv::Mat(), cv::Mat(), m_params, 10);

 //for prediction
 predicted = svmob.predict(testData);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SVM during training tries to find a separating hyperplane such that trainset examples lay on different sides. There could be many such hyperplanes (or none), so to select the "best" we look for the one for which total distance from all classes are maximized. Indeed, the further away from the hyperplane point is located — the more confident we are in the decision. So what we are interested in is distance to the hyperplane.

As per OpenCV [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/support_vector_machines.html#cvsvm-predict), `CvSVM::predict` has a default second arguments which specifies what to return. By default, it returns classification label, but you can pass in `true` and it'll return the distance.

The distance itself is pretty ok, but if you want to have a confidence value in a range (0, 1), you can apply [sigmoidal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) function to the result. One of such functions if logistic function.

```
decision = svmob.predict(testData, true);
confidence = 1.0 / (1.0 + exp(-decision));
```

Comment: But when I am giving same features used for training as test data, It returns a very low confidence value (0.268941), But for others it return high value (0.741124). Why it not giving higher confidence when train and test data are same ?

Comment: @deepak, well, actually it's a confidence of positive class (assuming binary classification). In order to get confidence of negative class, you should extract it from 1. Also, SVM doesn't memorize your trainset, it tries to find "internal structure" in your data, tries to fit a model. The model doesn't have to explain your trainset perfectly — otherwise it'd be an overfitting. Also, sometimes there is noise and outliers in your data — you don't want to take every single example too seriously.

Comment: will this be correct only if number of classes = 2 ?? .  In my case number of classes = 10.

Comment: Sigmiod is not a correct confidence in this case it's only a kind of confidence "simulation".

Comment: Use RVM classification for correct confidence computation.

Comment: @AndreySmorodov Smorodov Can you explain how to do that

Comment: See Bishop's book "Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning" p.353.
http://www.amazon.com/Pattern-Recognition-Learning-Information-Statistics/dp/0387310738

Comment: @AndreySmorodov, why not? It's not a probability (which I didn't claim to be), I agree, but it's a value from (0, 1) directly proportional to the confidence of SVM. The higher it is, the more SVM is "confident" about example.

Comment: From Bishop's book "The SVM is a decision machine and so does not provide posterior probabilities.
We have already discussed some of the benefits of determining probabilities in Section
1.5.4. An alternative sparse kernel technique, known as the relevance vector
Section 7.2 machine (RVM), is based on a Bayesian formulation and provides posterior probabilistic
outputs, as well as having typically much sparser solutions than the SVM."
I think it related also to fact that test points located far from training datapoints have lower confidence.

Comment: @AndreySmorodov, but the question is about confidence, not probability.

Comment: As I undestand the question "What the confidence that class belongs to predcted by classifier"? Is it not the same as "What the probability of the predicted class in given point in input space?" If yes, then it is posterior probabilities. BTW: RVM library: http://mi.eng.cam.ac.uk/~at315/MVRVM.htm

Comment: @Barmaley.exe will this be correct only if number of classes = 2 ??

Comment: @deepak, I could be wrong. If you have sigmoid's output less than 1/2, then signed distance to margin is less than 0. That means your datum is an outlier and doesn't fit into model (yes, this might be case even for trainset examples. The amount of such examples should be small, though).

Comment: @Barmaley.exe : this formula is giving high confidence even when I am giving non alphabet image (greater than 0.8). My current train size is 20000.

Comment: When I tested my svm model its giving 99 % accuracy. Its predicting character images correctly.. but when I giving a random image which doesn't contain any character, it is predicting one class with high confidence

Comment: @Artem Sobolev Any idea how to do this in OpenCV3? That boolean second parameter of `predict()` is no longer available.

Comment: @DavidDoria, I don't have any experience with OpenCV3, but from what I see in the documentation, you still can get raw scores by calling `predict` method (inherited from `cv::ml::StatModel`) with a flag `RAW_OUTPUT`. Alternatively, you can call `cv::ml::SVM::getDecisionFunction` to obtain all the parameters of the decision function, and compute it yourself (and then apply the sigmoid)

Comment: @ArtemSobolev Can you explain what `getDecisionFunction` does? I don't understand `alpha` and `svidx` from the docs (http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/ml/doc/support_vector_machines.html#svm-getdecisionfunction). Say we are using a linear SVM - `alpha` is all 1's (so not helpful for confidences). I don't understand which support vector indices this is returning in `svidx`? Like how do you "compute it yourself" (as you say) from this? Also, the `RAW_OUTPUT` only seems valid for a 2-class classifier (where presumably you'd be most interested in confidence in a multi-class problem?)

Comment: @DavidDoria, the decision function for SVM (whether linear or not) can be represented as `f(x) = ∑ᵢ αᵢ k(x, xᵢ)` where `xᵢ` is `i`th train example, and `k` is your kernel (just a scalar product in linear case). Summing over all of samples can be time-consuming, so it helps to use only non-zero alphas. Corresponding `x`s are called *support vectors* (hence the name of the algorithm), and their indices are given by `svidx`

Comment: @ArtemSobolev What does the actual value of `f(x)` look like/indicate? So `svidx` are the support vectors that contribute to the (from `getDecisionFunction(i, ...)`) ith decision function (out of the N*(N-1)/2) ? That is, the data samples that are the "closest" to the hyperplane dividing the two classes that the current decision function is delineating? Is there a way to get these hyperplanes directly? One could imagine a "confidence" score as a (somehow) normalized "distance to the nearest hyperplane", but I don't see any way to retrieve those. Any interest in updating the answer :) ?

Comment: @DavidDoria, presumably, the bigger the decision function `f(x)` is – the higher the probability that `x` belongs to the class. Also, it should be noted, that I forgot about the intercept: `getDecisionFunction` returns a scalar intercept, that should be added to the `f(x)`. The decision function gives you signed "distances" to the separating hyperplane, but you can't construct the hyperplane itself if you use non-trivial kernel.